# Azure IoT Hub integration with Azure Event Grid

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

So i have been going trying to integrate Azure IOT Hub with my local database
Just to be clear i already have devices that are connected with my IOT hub and they are sending the telemetry data
Seems like using Azure Event Grid is the way to go with webhook but unfortunately i haven't been able to find much. Is there any link or documentation that can point me in that direction

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what's the problem you're running into?

Comment: Never mind , the MsDoc was overwhelming but i got around to resolving it at last , now its working :)